# Find Character in String

Tags: java, arrays, converters

This is the code I have written to check if a String in a string array and to replace the character holding the same position in another String array.

```
char[][] currentGuessArray = new char[currentGuessPhrase.length][];
for (int x = 0; x < currentGuessPhrase.length; x++) {
    currentGuessArray[x] = currentGuessPhrase[x].toCharArray();
}
for (int x = 0; x < correctPhrase.length; x++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < correctPhrase[x].length(); a++) {
        if (correctPhrase[x].charAt(a) == guess) {
            currentGuessArray[x][a] = guess;
        }
    }
}
//Convert chars back to string array
for (int x = 0; x < currentGuessArray[x].length - 1; x++){
    currentGuessPhrase[x] = new String(currentGuessArray[x]);
}
```

For an example run: These are the values of `currentPhrase` (5 entries):

```
sunny banana noun trained named
```

Variable Guess:

```
guess = "a"
```

Expected output:

```
_____ _a___a ____ __a____ _a___
```

Actual output:

```
_____ ______ ____ _______ _____
```

Also, `for (int x = 0; x < currentGuessArray[x].length - 1; x++){`
Throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at a.updateGuess(a.java:97)
at a.main(a.java:110)
```

Anyone who could help with either of the problems would be greatly appreciated, and this is not homework.

Comment: Can you create [SSCCE?](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @vandale x is the string and a is the char placement.

Comment: String.indexOf(char) will find the position of the character in a String.  There's another version that will start from a given offset.

Comment: How do I assign all places of the char to given ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the loop that converts back from character arrays to strings: you should go to the length of the `currentGuessArray` array, not to the length of the first string in it:

```
//Convert chars back to string array
for (int x = 0; x < currentGuessArray.length ; x++) {
    currentGuessPhrase[x] = new String(currentGuessArray[x]);
}
```

With this fix in place, your code works ([demo](http://ideone.com/lGrOh3)).

Comment: @ModifyYou Actually, that's the only issue: check out your code in a demo.

Comment: I did an isolation test, and it works in that environment, but not in my code. What :/

Comment: Ah, I was simply declaring `guess` incorrectly, so it held a null value, therefore not changing any of the characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yeah,it works as like user dasblinkenlight says.but,i think that we can do this,more simple method, follow is my code:

```
/**
 * @param arr input array.
 * @param searchString search string.
 * @param replaceString replace string.
 * @return replace of the string later,got the modified array.
 */
public static String searchString(String [] arr, String searchString, String replaceString) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // search string whether or not exist.
        boolean isExist = arr[i].contains(searchString);
        if (!isExist) {
            continue;
        }
        // replace string.
        arr[i] = arr[i].replaceAll(searchString, replaceString);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result += arr[i] + (i != arr.length - 1 ? " " : "");
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

like this.it works when it called the method.